# Crystal Reports /rdlc reports in Java environments

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crystal-reports, report, rdlc

I'm looking for a way to use pre-designed rdlc reports or Crystal Reports in Java environments, such as IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Thanks for your time everyone!

So far I've found out about JasperReports and similar technologies, but I'm descarting that kind of solutions for the moment since I need to use rdlc or Crystal Reports.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking for a library to use within the IDE or within the application you are building? What output do you expect? A code example of how your report definitions are received is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What is the operating system?  If it is Windows, then there are simple solutions for integrating Crystal Reports into your solution.